# Wordpress Apache2 mod_speling not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-speling

I am in the process of migrating my site to Wordpress from IIS.

I have run into an issue:

- I have URL's that are a mix of upper and lower case that reference images.  These URL's are getting a 404 because the case of the URL does not match the case of the file location.

For example, in my article I have a URL:
https://aaa.bbb.com/wp-content/migrate/ABC/abc.png

The file this is referencing is: /var/www/aaa/wp-content/migrate/abc/abc.png

When I change the URL to the same case as the file, it works, however how can I make it ignore the case of the folder on disk?

I tired the mod_speling module by putting this into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf but this just does not work for me.  Also tried putting this into .htaccess in the root of my web directory but that made no difference.

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckSpelling On
  CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
```

I have read various threads on here but I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work around to this.

I ended up writing a rewrite rule in the VirtualHost file to rewrite everything to lowercase apart from anything within the directory of assets imported from Windows.